When I open a WPF window in my application, other system windows also come to front along with my window
I have a scenario where if I open a WPF child window from my application, if there were other system windows were open like MSpaint, or file explorer or any other application, then along with my child window, all those windows also come to front.
I am setting a window owner to application main window. I tried a few ways to explicitly activate child window through win32 API, but this did not work.
I used below APIs explicitly to keep my child window in front:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

I have tried to do:
var dialogHandle =
    new WindowInteropHelper(dialogWindow).Handle;
Win32Api.SetForegroundWindow(dialogHandle);
Win32Api.SetActiveWindow(dialogHandle);

This did not work though. Any idea what could be going wrong for such workflow?
I expect only the child window I am opening should remain open and stay in front, not other windows.

Having system windows coming to front when you create a child window is not normal behavior. You should focus on figuring out why it happens and using another way to prevent that instead of working around that problem. You should at least post the code of how you open the child window
